# Click on a nested div is not working with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple accordion. It was working but I had to add a div around the button area and now the click event is not working at all. Any help would be great.

```
<div class="accordion-ctn clearfix">
  <div class="accordion-button-ctn"><div class="accordion-button"><div class="title">Song Title 1</div></div><div class="button_ctn"><ul><li class="play_button"><a href="#">Play<img src="../../images/playBtn.png" alt="Play Button" /></a></li><li class="download_button"><a href="#">Download<img src="../../images/downloadBtn.png" alt="Download Button" /></a></li></ul></div></div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      Content here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$('.accordion-button').click(function() {
  $('.accordion-button').removeClass('on');
  $('.accordion-content').slideUp('normal');
  if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
    $(this).addClass('on');
    $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
  } 
});
```

Comment: 1. Are there any javascript errors? 2. using `$('.accordion-button')` in case that you have `$(this)` is just conceptually wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/SSBd4/